# Show that if $w^3=1$, then $1+w+w^2=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

> Find the cube root of unity. Hence, show that if $w^3=1$, then
>   $1+w+w^2=0$.

The cube root of unity is $1, -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $ -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. If $w^3=1$ then $w^3-1=0 \implies (w-1)(1+w+w^2)=0$
. The task is to prove that the second bracket is zero but we will only be sure that the second bracket is zero if the first is not zero, right? I think there is some assumption here that $w\ne1$ that I'm missing but I think that because $w^3=1$, $w$ can be any of the three roots of unity including $1$.

Comment: Yes, but it should have been stated explicitly.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen The world is never perfect.

Comment: "Find the primitive cubes root of unity". This is what was meant,

Comment: That's because the first bracket is zero for 1, so you can naturally assume w \ne 1$$ for the remainder of the proof

Answer (score 2):

The conditional is clearly not true for $w=1$. The hypothesis holds ($1^3=1$), but the conclusion does not ($1+1+1^2 \neq 0$). Therefore, you have to assume that $w \neq 1$ in order to conclude the proof.